# How do I embed a primefaces selectonemenu into a menubar?

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to use primfaces' selectonemenu and menubar for navigation, however I am having trouble getting the menubar to display the selectOneMenu as it only seems to want to recognize  tags and not  tags. Any ideas?

menubar http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/menubar.jsf
selectOneMenu http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

Comment: What do you mean Tags and Not Tags?  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Toolbar` instead of a `Menubar`:

```
<p:toolbar>
    <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
           <p:selectOneMenu>
               <f:selectItem itemValue="Red" itemLabel="Red"/>
               <f:selectItem itemValue="Blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
               <f:selectItem itemValue="Green" itemLabel="Green"/>
               <!-- other components -->
           </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

Produces:

[image]